.NET 8 API with SQL Server: Error During Login Process
I am using .NET 8 to create an API that connects to a SQL Server. My connection string is as follows:
configuration["ConnectionStrings:DBConnection"] = "Data Source=\"MYIP, MYPORT\\SQL_I5\";Initial Catalog=Pr;User ID=sa;Password=myPassword;Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=true";

However, I am receiving the following error:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The specified data could not be decrypted.

I have tried the following solutions:

Adding TrustServerCertificate=true
Setting Encrypt=false
Using both true and false in uppercase and lowercase for these parameters

Despite these attempts, the issue persists. How can I resolve this login process error?

This isn't about the trust of the certificate, it's an SSL error. It's odd that you have Encrypt set to false but TrustServerCertificate set to true; if encryption was off this means that there's no certificate to trust (as it's not being used).

I have also tried setting only Encrypt=false without the TrustServerCertificate parameter, but the same error persists.
configuration["ConnectionStrings:DBConnection"] = "Data Source="MYIP, MYPORT\SQL_I5";Initial Catalog=Pr;User ID=sa;Password=myPassword;Encrypt=false";
Under normal circumstances, I connect to the database with a connection string that includes the credentials and Encrypt=false, and it works fine. However, when connecting from the .NET API, I encounter this error.
Any insights on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Some of the Googling I've done suggests it's an (old) Windows bug; what release and version of Windows are you using? For example, Windows 11 23H2,

What's happening with the connection string? You'd normally specify ServerNameOrIpAddress,PortNumber or ServerNameOrIpAddress\InstanceName but you seem to be mixing the two together.

The login7 packet in the MS-TDS protocol is always encrypted regardless of whether the rest of the communication channel is encrypted or not. I wonder if you could just be connecting to an incredibly old SQL Server... what's the output of SELECT @@VERSION when executed against the target SQL Server instance? And what version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient are you using?

My Sql version is Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-GDR) (KB5040936) - 16.0.1121.4 (X64)   Jul  2 2024 00:22:34   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 19045: )
In my project: 

Thanks for the reply, on the string connection I have to mix that. PORT/SQL_I5

"W10 PRO 23H2" there's no such thing... "Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 19045)" which you state above is 22H2.

oh my bad sir, its W11 23H2 S.O version 22631.3737

It's my understanding that when connecting to a named instance, you cannot specify the port. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver16

Try to access the server using tcp. If the computers are not in the same Network Share then tcp is the good choice. Do not forget to enable TCP connections and set up firewall rules on the server.
Example connection string: Server=tcp:192.168.1.10,1443;Initial Catalog=...;. Every time you are not sure about your connection string this website will help you: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Thanks for the awnser but still doesnt work for me.
